# Identifying a particular node in XML using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am working with an XML document and I am not sure how to parse it to find a particular node.

In the example below I'd be searching for the  ProductB and expecting to identify the  Bee Hive

```
<PRODUCTS>
    <PRODUCT_LEVEL_1>
        <PRODUCT_ID>ProductA</PRODUCT_ID>
        <PRODUCT_NAME>Ant Hill</PRODUCT_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_ID>ProductB</PRODUCT_ID>
        <PRODUCT_NAME>Bee Hive</PRODUCT_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_ID>ProductC</PRODUCT_ID>
        <PRODUCT_NAME>Centipede Hotel</PRODUCT_NAME>
    </PRODUCT_LEVEL_1>
</PRODUCTS>
```

I'm not even sure how to refer to this format of XML which is making it difficult to search for.

Any assistance gratefully received.

Edit: At present I am loading the XML from a file using the following:

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument] $xd = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$file = resolve-path($inputFile)
$xd.load($file)
$nodelist = $xd.selectnodes("/PRODUCTS/PRODUCT_LEVEL_1")
foreach ($documentNode in $nodelist) {
    #do some stuff
}
```

The actual XML file has loads of other junk in too but I stripped it out in the hopes of focusing on the bits I need.  Perhaps I have stripped too much and the context has been lost?

Comment: EDIT:  Why does the comment section not keep my line breaks?!
Thanks for the quick response PetSerAl.

I am wondering how to use that in my existing code.

At the moment I have loaded the XML document and selected all the nodes of <PRODUCT> into a $nodelist.  I am then using a foreach to loop through each <PRODUCT> node.

Comment: I can't figure out how to post the code - every time I hit enter it takes it as a comment!!

Comment: Thanks for that too!  :)

Comment: Replace your `SelectNodes()` argument with the `-Xpath` value @PetSerAl suggested

Comment: Ah - I see.  Much appreciated to you both.

Comment: The comment section does not keep line breaks because comments are supposed to be small.  That's why there's such a small character limit.  If you need to add code or a significant amount of detail, you should edit your question and add it there.  That way, future readers don't need to read through all the comments to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath for this task. XPath have axes, which allows you to refer preceding and following elements of document:

```
filter Prepare-StringForXPath {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [String]$String
    )
    if($String -notlike '*''*') {
        "'$String'"
    } elseif($String -notlike '*"*') {
        """$String"""
    } else {
        “concat($(($String -split '(?<=''[^"]*)(?=")|(?<="[^'']*)(?='')' | Prepare-StringForXPath) -join ', '))”
    }
}

$xd = [Xml]@'
<PRODUCTS>
    <PRODUCT_LEVEL_1>
        <PRODUCT_ID>ProductA</PRODUCT_ID>
        <PRODUCT_NAME>Ant Hill</PRODUCT_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_ID>ProductB</PRODUCT_ID>
        <PRODUCT_NAME>Bee Hive</PRODUCT_NAME>
        <PRODUCT_ID>ProductC</PRODUCT_ID>
        <PRODUCT_NAME>Centipede Hotel</PRODUCT_NAME>
    </PRODUCT_LEVEL_1>
</PRODUCTS>
'@

$ProdName = Read-Host 'Input product name'
$ProdID = $xd.SelectSingleNode("//PRODUCT_NAME[.=$(Prepare-StringForXPath $ProdName)]/preceding-sibling::PRODUCT_ID[1]").InnerText
"Product ID for '$ProdName' is '$ProdID'."

$ProdID = Read-Host 'Input product ID'
$ProdName = $xd.SelectSingleNode("//PRODUCT_ID[.=$(Prepare-StringForXPath $ProdID)]/following-sibling::PRODUCT_NAME[1]").InnerText
"Product name for '$ProdID' is '$ProdName'."
```